# Obfuscation of Mei Raglayim in translation

Tags: translation, prayer-book

I have noticed that many siddurim and machzorim render the term מי רגלים (in the recitation of [the *k'tores* recipe](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA)) as "mei raglayim" rather than translating it to its actual definition, urine.

Siddurim I have personally seen this in:

- Gamaliel Ben Pedahzur Siddur (London, 1750s)
- Alexander Siddur (London, 1750s)
- Siddur Tehillat Hashem (Brooklyn, 1977 and 2002)

Is there any rationale for doing this, when those who understand the Hebrew will immediately know what it means?

Comment: Aside from Chabad's *Tehilas Hashem*, have you seen any other contemporary siddur that avoids translating מי רגלים?

Comment: I have read (looking for the location) that the substance referred to is not urine, but non-potable water that smelled bad and was known colloquially by that name. If so, it would explain sticking to the term, whose meaning would be more obscured by rendering it literally. The circumstantial support for this explanation is that the _g'mara_ in _Yoma_ specifically says that it must not be used because of its odor.

Comment: @Fred, I only gave those three because they were the ones on hand. I will consult any other siddurim if I am able to find translations available.

Comment: @WAF *Y'rushalmi Yoma* 4:5: והלא מי רגלים יפין לה אלא שאין מכניסין ריח רע לעזרה מפני הכבוד

Comment: @Fred Yes, thank you. And I can't help but add that _mei raglayim_ is itself a euphemism for, rather than the translation of "urine".

Comment: @WAF I was thinking that, too. Perhaps there's some source that explicitly advises perpetuating the Talmud's euphemisms in translation.

Comment: @Fred, even so, wouldn't an English euphemism be preferable in an English translation?

Comment: @Fred Well, it might simply be a clearer/better translation that way. [Here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_36246_94.pdf) is a reference to the _Kolbo_ saying that _mei raglayim_ was the name of a spring (lower right hand column).

Comment: @WAF Wow, the באר שבע is really strongly opposed to that explanation (mentioned as an alternative יש מפרשים in *Kol Bo* 38).

Comment: @Fred _Baruch shekivanta l'divrei Ba'er Hetev_ - [bottom of #8](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/pagepngs/14164_29_1190_1615.png).

Comment: I think Birnbaum also transliterates and does not state "urine". I think leaving the transliteration is preferable. What do you want them to call it. Pee?

Comment: FWIW, Artscroll translates as "urine."

Comment: @Shokhet, I know, I checked that during my research for this question.

Comment: @DanF No, he wants them to use "urine" which isn't childish and inappropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This morning, I davened in a shul that I don't normally daven in, and I noticed that they had some siddurim that I don't usually see around. So I decided to do some research for your question, and here's what I found:

Siddur Tehillat Hashem (fourth edition, April 2004) translates מי רגלים as "water of Raglayim," and cites the gemara [Kerisus 6a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=35&daf=6&format=pdf)-b (both sources already cited [by Menachem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52659/5323)), as well as Yerushalmi Yoma 4:5. (page 243, footnote 1)

The Metsudah Shabbos/Yom Tov Siddur (fourth edition, 1984) also translates מי רגלים as "water of Raglayim," and cites *Kol Bo* as explaining that there was a well that was called "Raglayim," whose water was good for this purpose, but couldn't be brought into the Temple, because מי רגלים is also a euphemism for urine. They also say (also in the name of the *Kol Bo*) that מי רגלים might actually mean urine. (page 173, footnotes 10-11)

Artscroll, as mentioned in comments, does actually translate מי רגלים as urine, as does the Koren Mesorat HaRav Siddur.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps because not everyone translates "Mei Raglayim" as urine.

[The Shitah Mekubetzet (Chof-Chet) to Kritot 6A](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37968&pgnum=676) brings 2 translations of "Mei Raglayin". The first being actual urine, but the second being a grass with that name. And the name makes it an embarrassment to use it for service in the Beit Hamikdash.

I also remember reading another explanation that it was water of the river Raglayim, but I can't remember where I saw it. [Although it seems that the comments to the question bring several sources for this.] -- Note that [the Siddur Tehillat Hashem actually translates it as](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&pgnum=55) "water of **R**aglayim" [note the capital R], which suggests that they are translating it according to this explanation

Comment: +1, but I don't think the capital R means that much. It was standard English to capitalize foreign words (in the typewriter era). Now italics is preferred, but this may be a holdover.

Comment: "water of the river Raglayim" -- perhaps "well of Raglayim"? See [my answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52676/5323)